# About MIssingComponentException in Unity(vscode)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to make "Color Change" button using simple project file.

But error message

"There is no "SpriteRenderer" attached to the "Image" game object, but a script is trying to access it.

occured...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Colorchange : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject MainCharacter;
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public void change()
    {
        MainCharacter.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color= Color.red;
    }
}
```